# Ant fileset wildcard in dir attribute

Tags: ant

I have multiple projects in my Eclipse workspace: *Version 1*, *Version 2*, *Version 3*, etc

I would like to include the .class files from each of these directories into an output .jar file. I want the .class files placed into the root of the jar file.

Something like this:

```
<fileset dir="../Version*" includes="*.class" />
```

However, this doesn't work. This does:

```
<fileset dir=".." includes="Version*/*.class" />
```

But in the output jar file, the files are being included into directories. E.g. *Version 1/Version1.class*, *Version 2/Version2.class*

This is not what I want. I want *Version1.class* and *Version2.class* to be in the root of the jar file.

Hope I explained that well, let me know if clarification is needed - and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to equip your `<jar` task with a Mapper. With that mapper, cut away the first folder component. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me, unless I'm using the mapper wrong. I get the error: `jar doesn't support the nested "mapper" element.`

Comment: Nonetheless, I managed to solve my issue using MultiRootFileSet.

Comment: Combining the mapper and `mappedresources` http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources would be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was only a few Google searches away from figuring this out.

Here's a solution that worked for me:

```
<pathconvert property="versions" pathsep=",">
    <dirset dir=".." includes="Versions*" />
</pathconvert>
```

And then in the jar task:

```
<multirootfileset basedirs="${versions}" type="file" includes="*.class" />
```

Requires Ant 1.9.4